# Does the equation $U^2+V^2=A^2+sB^2$ with $s$ squarefree have a complete integer solution?

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I’m looking for a complete solution (parameterization or other) to the equation in the title, *i.e.*,
$$
  U^2+V^2=A^2+sB^2,
$$
where $s$ is squarefree [if necessary]. When $s=1$, the solution is well-known (and easy to derive), so we can assume $s \ne 1$.

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't seem to know the well known solution for $s=1.$

Comment: @WillJagy: If $u,v,a,b$ are integers, with $uvab \ne 0$, such that
$u^2+v^2 = a^2+b^2,$
then there exist integers $g,h,m,n,t$ such that 
\begin{align}
 u &= \tfrac{1}{2}t(hn+gm),  &\qquad\qquad&&  a &= \tfrac{1}{2}t(hn-gm),  \\
 v &= \tfrac{1}{2}t(hm-gn), &\qquad\qquad&&  b &= \tfrac{1}{2}t(hm+gn),
\end{align}
where $t$ is the greatest common divisor of $u,v,a,b$, and $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: can't see anything; will try refreshing the screen in a minute. Dickson's History, Volume 2, page 254, says Welsch  (1910) claimed the full solution is... alright, same as what you type.

Comment: On page 503, Fricke and Klein suggest $(z_1z_4 - z_2 z_3)$ as a normal form for an isotropic quaternary quadratic form, signature $++--.$ Seems to give Welsh's result without trouble...

Comment: hmmm. appears that helps for $U^2 + s V^2 = A^2 + s B^2.$ Your version, not so much. You might try $u^2 + v^2 = a^2 + 27 b^2,$ where things about the cube root of two should appear. Or, worse, $u^2 + v^2 = a^2 + 23 b^2,$

Comment: @WillJagy: Page 503 in what book? My Dickson Vol II doesn't have anything like that on page 503.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Theorie+der+automorphen++Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false

Answer (score 1):

For the equation.

$$U^2+W^2=A^2+tB^2$$

You can write such a parameterization.

$$U=2ps(z^2+tq^2+x^2-y^2)+2x((p^2-s^2)y+(p^2+s^2)z)$$

$$W=(p^2-s^2)(z^2+tq^2-x^2+y^2)+2y(2psx+(p^2+s^2)z)$$

$$A=(p^2+s^2)(z^2-tq^2+x^2+y^2)+2z(2psx+(p^2-s^2)y)$$

$$B=2q(2psx+(p^2-s^2)y+(p^2+s^2)z)$$